# print image in air without dialogue while fit image to page

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, printing, air

I want to print an image from a webcam without showing a printer dialogue and the image should fit the page. (Using AIR and Flex)

There are two options:
use **FlexPrintJob**

```
var printjob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
printjob.start();
printjob.addObject(image as IUIComponent,FlexPrintJobScaleType.SHOW_ALL);
printjob.send();
```

But: this will show the printer dialogue.

use **PrintJob**

```
var printjob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
printjob.start2();
printjob.addPage(imageSprite);
printjob.send();
```

But: this won't scale the image to fit the page.

Any ideas how to achieve both?

Currently I think it's only possible to use the PrintJob and scale the image to fit the page by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
var printjob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
if(printjob.start()){
  var scale:Number;
  myScale=Math.min(printjob.pageWidth/imageSprite.width,printjob.pageHeight/imageSprite.height);
  imageSprite.scaleX = imageSprite.scaleY = myScale;
  var printArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, printjob.pageWidth/myScale, printjob.pageHeight/myScale);
}else{
//-- user cancelled or error occured.
}
printjob.addPage(imageSprite, printArea);
printjob.send();
```

Comment: no this wont work :(
first I dont want to see the print dialogue which is shown and second problem is the printed sprite is not the size my image is.
But thanks for your help...